# How to combine different values of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, iteration, ienumerable

Struggling with the concept of this: I have a method that returns an `IEnumerable` like so:

```
public IEnumerable<IFruit> FruitStall(IEnumerable<IFruit> fruits)...
```

and each `IFruit` is as follows

```
public decimal Amount { get; }
public string Code { get; }
```

and my `FruitsStall` method returns one `IFruit` per currency with the sum of all money of the same code.

e.g

```
{APL10, APL20, APL50} => {APLE80}
or
{APL10, APL20, ORG50} => {APL30, ORG50}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of this? Not too sure how to go about this.

I was looping through the `IEnumerable` with a

```
foreach (var item in fruits)
{
    fruits.Code
}
```

but unsure where to go there on

Comment: Can't understand what you want; you start out describing what your method already does, and then you ask if anyone can help with it. Help with what? If you method already does X then what is left to help you with? By the way, strive to make method names verbs rather than nouns.

Answer (score 1):

When you said:

```
{APL10, APL20, APL50} => {APLE80}
or
{APL10, APL20, ORG50} => {APL30, ORG50}
```

If you meant

> I have this: `{new Fruit("APL",10), new Fruit("APL", 20), new Fruit("ORG",50)}` and I want to generate a list like `{new Fruit("APL",30), new Fruit("ORG",50)}`

I would say:

You need to have some container that can hold all the different codes and map them to a sum of Amounts. For this we often use a dictionary:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();
foreach(var f in fruit){
  if(!d.ContainsKey(f.Code))
    d[f.Code] = f.Amount;
  else
    d[f.Code] += f.Amount;
}
```

At the end of this operation your dictionary will contain a unique set of fruit codes and the sum of all the amounts. You can turn it back into a list of fruit by enumerating the dictionary and creating a list in a similar way to how you created the list initially

Once you get your head round that, you can take a look at using LINQ, and do something like:

```
var summedFruits = fruits
  .GroupBy(f => f.Code)
  .Select(g => new Fruit(g.Key, g.Sum(f => f.Amount)));
```

(This assumes your Fruit has a constructor that takes a Code and an Amount). When you GroupBy in LINQ you get an output that is like a List of Lists. The original input list is broken up into some number of lists; where everything in each list has the same value for what you declared was the key (I said to group by code)

So your original representation:

```
{APL10, APL20, ORG50}
```

Would end up looking like:

```
Key = APL, List = {APL10, APL20}
Key = ORG, List = {ORG50}
```

Your "one list of three things" has become "a list of (a list of two APL ) and (a list of one ORG)"

If you then run a select on them you can create a new Fruit that uses the Key as the code and sums up the amount in each list

```
Key = APL, List = {APL10, APL20}, Sum = 30
Key = ORG, List = {ORG50}, Sum = 50
```

In this code:

```
var summedFruits = fruits
  .GroupBy(f => f.Code)
  .Select(g => new Fruit(g.Key, g.Sum(f2=> f2.Amount)));
```

`f` is a fruit, one of the items in the original list of 3 fruits. We group by the fruit's code. `g` is the result of the grouping operation, it is a "list of fruit with a common code", the Key is the code (apl or org). `g` is a list, so you can call sum on it. Every item inside the g list is a fruit, which is why I switch back to `f` (when I say f2), to help remember that it's an individual fruit- we're summing the amount. For the first list of APL the sum is 30. At the end of the operation a new List results; one with two elements - an APL and an ORG, but the Amounts are the summations of all

Comment: Btw you don't need the .Select (and enumerate twice).
The sum up can also be accomplished when grouping:

`var summedFruits = fruits.GroupBy(f => f.Code, (k, fs) => new Fruit(k, fs.Sum(f=> f.Amount)));`

Comment: I'm not sure all parts of your comment are correct though I agree that your suggestion is a condensed equivalent of the code posted. In any case I broke it out for educational reasons; I already think a LINQ solution is a bridge too far, without looking to golf it too

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = fruits.GroupBy(x => x.Code).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.Amount));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.